# Is this possible to do in RethinkDB

Tags: php, rethinkdb

I've used mongodb in the past and I want to use similar schema. I've tried to create it using PHP driver but it doesn't work as I expected. So my guesses were either rethinkdb does not support it or php driver is not capable to do this.

```
r\table('User')->insert([
        'username' => 'Something',
        'skills' => [
            'php' => 10,
            'html' => 15 
        ]
        ])->run($conn)
```

result in RethinkDB administrator js client:

```
{
    "username":  "Something" ,
    "id":  "899a2693-dd94-4670-a496-05626a88d190" ,
    "skills": { }
}
```

What do you suggest and how should I do this?

Comment: The quoted array is missing a ' after Something - it should be 'Something', not 'Something,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work with PHP 5.4.13, RethinkDB 1.5.1 and the lastest version of php-rql.

```
r\table('User')->insert([
        'username' => 'Something',
        'skills' => [
            'php' => 10,
            'html' => 15 
        ]
])->run($conn);
```

It gives the following results:

```
$result = r\db("test")->table("user")->run($conn);
print_r($result->toNative());


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => Something
            [skills] => Array
                (
                    [php] => 10
                    [html] => 15
                )

            [id] => 2c66490f-72da-49ad-9692-a85366ce94ab
        )

)
```

And in the Data Explorer:

```
[

    {
        "username": "Something" ,
        "skills": {
            "php": 10 ,
            "html": 15
        } ,
        "id": "2c66490f-72da-49ad-9692-a85366ce94ab"
    }

]
```

Comment: I had update later in the code and haven't noticed. Thanks, your answer made me recheck everything.